# How does one properly setup Pyramid and ZeroMQ to provide a simple chat/messaging interface?

Tags: python, pyramid, zeromq, server-sent-events

I'm trying to build a Pyramid app that uses ZeroMQ to provide a very simple chat/messaging interface, but I can't seem to figure out the proper setup/workflow.

The structure seems straightforward enough to me, and in its simplest form could be described in as little as two Pyramid "views"/routes:

1. **The client SSE "show messages" view:** This view/route would remain open to the client (using Server-Sent Events on the client-side and Pyramid's `response.app_iter` on the server-side), listening for messages from ZeroMQ and `yield`ing them up to the client as they are received.
2. **The "submit a new message" view:** This view/route would receive POST requests containing a single message's data, which it would then pass to ZeroMQ to be received in the SSE view and displayed to any clients listening there.

For some reason however, I have not been able to come up with the correct recipe for accomplishing this feat. Google seems to be pretty sparse when it comes to recipes for 0MQ and Pyramid, and all of my own hacking has either resulted in Python/Pyramid thread/process problems, or 0MQ never being able to send or receive any messages (which is probably related to my threading issues).

So, how does one properly build this kind of an app with Pyramid?

P.S. You may assume any version of Python/Pyramid, etc in your answers. The point is to just get something that works as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a proof of concept of exactly that a few years back.

https://github.com/antoineleclair/zmq-sse-chat

Comment: Looks like exactly what I'm describing, but I can't seem to get it to work. What's your setup (Pyramid version, WSGI/server config, etc)?

Comment: Just `python setup.py develop` and `pserve development.ini --reload` it. Last time I checked (~feb. 2014) it worked fine. I did not try it behind a reverse proxy or with other wsgi server than Waitress.

Comment: On Pyramid 1.5 beta using Waitress it starts fine but hangs when the `event` route is loaded (`msg = socket2.recv()` appears to be blocking all other requests). If I run it using something like Gunicorn using GeventWorker, I get ZMQ's dreaded "Assertion failed: ok (mailbox.cpp:84)" error which apparently has to do with thread issues.

Comment: Just addded Mako dependency to make it run with Pyramid 1.5. Worked just fine on Chrome/Ubuntu 13.10. You can try to isolate the problem by replacing the zmq thing in the generator with a static string and a time.sleep(1), to make sure the problem is really on the SSE side (and not ZMQ)

Comment: Ah, now I see: you're using Pylons' old `Paste#http` server. Newer versions of Pyramid use `waitress` by default which appears to be prone to blocking.

Any chance you could give me a working example using something more "production ready" such as Gunicorn or Gevent? My personal preference would be Gunicorn using the `gunicorn.workers.ggevent.GeventWorker` worker class: http://pastebin.com/UUDrGNJi

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I don't have time to put on this right now. Good luck though, and let me know (pull request?) if you make it more production ready.